# How to display a Dialog from the onClick(View v) method inside of the ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, dialog, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show a Dialog(custom) , when the user taps on an item in the RecyclerView , but i wasn't able to figure out how , can someone give me an example code? Thanks a lot

Comment: show your current code,so that we could rectify it, if possible

Answer (score 0):

Give us some example code or at least try to come up with something. Did you do any reasearch?

```
private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.myview, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
The onClick method:

@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
    String item = mList.get(itemPosition);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```